# What is a good model for predicting which item the user will select from a list?

Tags: sorting, user-interface

I have a list of apps the user has installed, a history of all previously opened apps, and a series of characters that the user has input.

The user is shown a list of apps filtered taking into account the input, the specific function should be given, but the app the user wants must never be filtered out. The list of apps the user is shown is sorted by some ordering given, but order should not change for the N (N is given and small ~10) most probable apps if character is added to the input.

The objective is to predict the most probable apps the user wants opened, and sort them from most probable to least and not jarringly re-sort the apps the moment the user goes to click.

Is there a *correct* way to achieve this? How should I think a solution for this? Is there a model for the user?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the character input to affect the list of most probable apps, don't use the character input to predict the list of suggested apps.

If you use the character input to predict a list of suggested apps, then changing the character input has the possibility to change the list of suggested apps.

Alternatively, calculate a list of suggested apps when you first start displaying the list, then don't re-calculate it -- save that list, and continue to use that same list for some period of time, regardless of what additional character input might be provided.

There is no way to say what is "correct", because you haven't given a clearly specified criteria of what counts as correct.  There are just some approaches with different tradeoffs.

Comment: The problem is with changing the order of the most probable apps, not with changing the list (the list can be reduced and most items can be reordered). Also, how do I decide what apps are the most probable based on history?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a function $f(input, apphistory, task)$ that returns the set of matching apps where $input$ is a string the user has entered (eg: the command name), $apphistory$ is a frequency distribution of the previous app launches (for inferring the most frequently used apps) and $task$ is an additional filter criteria that is associated with apps.

```
SELECT 
 app_name, historical_use_count 
FROM apphistory 
WHERE 
 app_name like @input AND
 task = @task
ORDER BY historical_use_count desc
```

A query like the above would filter apps suitable for the task at hand and sort them by historical frequency of use. You could then have the app restrict to the Top N results from the query to display in the UI.

This of course assumes that you have already associated the tasks with the apps and have that already tagged to the app (eg: as a column in the apphistory)

Comment: Can tasks be determined via some unsupervised learning algorithm, like oja's? What kind of information is most useful when generating the probability, do the tasks influence the probability of opening an app more than the apphistory? Is the generation of probabilities from the apphistory straightforward or does your user model take into account some possible nonintutive behaviors?

Comment: If you want to add weightages using a learning algorithm, you can do that and update the apphistory table or maintain the learned <app_name, weights> tuple in a separate table and join them in the query and sort it however you like.